# Job preferences: entering additional cities should not imply "Open to relocation"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

What if I am willing to work remotely, but restrict it to the Netherlands.
Because it should be easy for me and the company to organize regular personal meetings. For example once a month for 2 or 3 days?

"Willing to work remotely" does not necessarily imply the whole world.

Living in The Hague and only including the current home as location does not imply: "I am willing to commute to Amsterdam".

So I get filtered out by companies located in Amsterdam, because I did not enter Amsterdam, because I don't want to be shown as: "Willing to relocate to Amsterdam".

Another reason:

I want to express, that I want to work in City X,Y,Z but not in City A, because commuting 1 hour (one way) to city A is not what I want.
Even when it is not uncommon in this country to accept long commuting times.

So I pick some cities around my home location which are easy/fast to reach. But I dont want to relocate to these cities.

Comment: There's even more very good reasons for wanting to work remotely but only with employers in your home country: starting permanent employment is trivial in your own country but even crossing a EU border can make things very difficult, requiring huge amounts of paperwork, going freelance, or using an umbrella company. Not everyone wants that. Also, in your own country you are guaranteed access to worker protection, legally imposed benefits/vacation days, enforceability of contracts, help in case of complaints...