# Job preferences: I am not willing to relocate to ... my home location

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In job preferences I checked the boxes for:

- "Always include your current location"
- "Willing to work remotely"

In the developer story "Traditional view" it shows:
"You are open to relocating to < my home location >"

I am looking for jobs at my home location plus I am willing to work remotely otherwise.

The system should be smart enough to know that working at my home location is not "relocating".

Comment: I can't help the fact that I don't understand what your question is at all. Could you please elaborate further on what you'd like to be answered by fellow SO users? For me and any clueless others.

Comment: It makes no sense that my current location (Home) is City X, and in the developer story I am shown as: Willing to relocate to X.

Comment: Can I ask, what is the main difference between [your other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374471/job-preferences-entering-additional-cities-should-not-imply-open-to-relocation), and this one?  I'm not sure I understand how they differ.

Comment: @luqo33 It's a bug report...

Comment: @gravitymixes This is a bug report about the fact that it considers your home location as relocating.  The other question is a feature request to restrict remote working to a geographical area.

Answer (score 4):

Good catch!

There was a logic error in our front-end code. The bug also affected some employer-facing pages, so this is a double win, yay.

The fix will be live with the next build.

Thanks for your report.